# 1D diffusion problem: Troublesome NeumannValue

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 13.1 or earlier and fixed in 13.2.0**

---

*Mathematica* solves the diffusion problem (two Neumann-conditions)

```
U = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] ==Derivative[0, 2][u][t, x] +
NeumannValue[-u[t, x], x == 0]+
Boole[t <= 10] (1 +  $MachineEpsilon)   NeumannValue[1,x == 1], u[0, x] == 0}, u, {x,0, 1}, {t, 0, 20}  ]

Plot3D[U[t, x], {t, 0, 20}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,AxesLabel -> {t, x, u}]
```

without problems.

[image]

But the second Neumann-condition

```
Boole[t <= 10] (1 +  $MachineEpsilon)   NeumannValue[1,x == 1]
```

seems to be very sensitive near `Boole[t <= 10]  1`!

If I change to "undisturbed Neumann condition"

```
U = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0][u][t, x] ==Derivative[0, 2][u][t, x] +NeumannValue[- 
u[t, x], x == 0]
+ Boole[t <= 10] 1   NeumannValue[1,x == 1], u[0, x] == 0}, u,{x,0, 1}, {t, 0, 20}  ]
```

Mathematica gives the wrong(?) solution `U[t,x]==0`

What's wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: "Thereby the second Neumann-condition" I think by "thereby" you mean "But"?

Comment: Actually `$MachineEpsilon` isn't necessary. `Boole[t <= 10] 1. NeumannValue[1, x == 1]` is enough. I believe this is a parsing error i.e. when the coefficient of `NeumannValue[…]` doesn't involve `MachinePrecision` number, the whole `NeumannValue[…]` is missing. Let's wait for confirmation from user21 :) .

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, I changed the wording.

Comment: @xzczd, I started looking into this. It seems the problem is that compiled Bool will return an integer but the compiled code expects a real. Let's see if I can improve on that. This is really a special case as Bool can change domain it returns; a bit like Sqrt.

Comment: @user21 Good to know that `Boole` causes the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug. The problem is that a compiled Boole will return an integer but the compiled FEM code expects a real. This is really a special case as Boole can change domain it returns; a bit like Sqrt. I have committed a fix for this for version 13.2. In the mean time use

```
1.*Boole[expr]
```

to force this to be a real value. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for reporting.